# A set or its complement that contains an finite intersection, when the infinite one vanishes.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying the following statement but without much succes: Let $X$ be a set, and suppose we have sets $\{C_i \subseteq X \ \rvert \ i \in I \}$ for some index $I. \ $
Now assume that: $$\bigcap_{i \in I} C_i = \emptyset $$
Then for every $A \subset X$ there is $J \subseteq I$ finite such that:
$$A \supseteq \bigcap_{j \in J}C_j \ \text{ or } \ X/A \supseteq \bigcap_{j \in J}C_j$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not true.

Suppose $X=[0,1]$, $I=\mathbb{N}$ and $C_n=(0,1/n)$, then we have that
$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_n= \emptyset $$
Now, take $A=\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, then given any finite set $J \subset \mathbb{N}$ if we define $m$ as its maximum, we have that
$$\bigcap_{j \in J} C_j = (0,1/m)$$
and clearly, $(0,1/m) \not \subset A$ and $(0,1/m) \not \subset X \setminus A$.

Comment: Nice counterexample!